# How can Filebeat specify match rules to Logstash

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, filebeat

I want to let Logstash'gork filter use the match rules which Filebeat give

Here is my Filebeat config:

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /root/Log-test/test.log
  fields:
    "@metadata":
        formatter: "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} - %{NOTSPACE:module} - %{LOGLEVEL:level} - %{NOTSPACE:filename} - %{GREEDYDATA:log_message}"
  fields_under_root: true

output.logstash:
  hosts: ["localhost:5045"]
```

Here is my Logstash config:

```
input {
    beats {
        port => "5045"
    }
}

filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{[@metadata][formatter]}" }
  }
}

output {
  file {
    path => "/tmp/log-test.log"
    codec => rubydebug { metadata => true }
  }
}
```

So, i want the grok know my match rules content (the `message` field) is `"%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} - %{NOTSPACE:module} - %{LOGLEVEL:level} - %{NOTSPACE:filename} - %{GREEDYDATA:log_message}"`

But the setting above do not work, I want to know how can i implement the funciton like this? or is it possible to make it?

Thanks!

Comment: Verify that the metadata is coming as expected:  output {
  stdout {
    codec  => rubydebug {
      metadata => true
    }
  }
}

Comment: @AlainCollins i have verify the the metadata, and yes it has included the ```formatter``` field

Comment: @AlainCollins the data is fine, the problem is how to assign the data to ```message``` field, and i have watch the [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.7/event-dependent-configuration.html) and it seem that Logstash prefer to assign data through string format and that has     crush with grok match style

Answer (score 1):

From this [posting](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-get-grok-filter-from-variable/118511/2), "Grok expressions with dynamic %{field} references aren't supported".  The original author of that post opened a github issue, which is now [here](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-grok/issues/134) (and unresolved after a year).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have also got an Elastic member's reply and it seem not possible to use dynamic %{field} as grok patterns, refer to my post in Elastic discuss [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-can-filebeat-send-match-rules-to-logstash/176814)